# difference about select * and select column about THE index

Tags: mysql

A sample of index usage is shown below in create table query:

```
drop table test_index;
create table test_index(
    id bigint not null auto_increment ,
    `name` varchar(20) not null default '',
    uid bigint not null default 0,
    a int not null default 0,
    b int not null default 0,
    primary key(id),
    index `a_b`  (a,b) 
);
```

What's the difference between

```
select  * from test_index where a =10
```

and

```
select name from test_index where a=10
```

about THE index.

-------update---------

maybe question is

What's the difference between

```
select  * from test_index where a =10
```

and

```
select a from test_index where a=10
```

about THE index.

Comment: The index should help the `WHERE` clause identify records which should be returned.  I would expect this process to not have anything to do with the number of columns being returned.  The index concerns finding _records_, not columns.

Comment: Unless the select list contains only such fields that are in the index. In that case MySQL will not even open the table itself.

Comment: I have updated my answer providing more info using explain for both queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL indexes have several goals. Probably the most common ones are:

- To find the rows, matching the `WHERE` clause.
- To discard rows from consideration.

For more information, [check here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html)

But looking at the results of running explain in both queries, it seems to show some differences.

```
explain select * from test_index where a = 10;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_index | NULL       | ref  | a_b           | a_b  | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+

explain select a from test_index where a = 10;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_index | NULL       | ref  | a_b           | a_b  | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
```

If we focus on the Extra field we notice there is a difference. For the first query its value is **null** while is **Using index** for the second one.

Looking at the docs, we can see what this differences mean:

- From the [explain docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information) for the **Using index** value in the Extra column: 
  *The column information is retrieved from the table using only information in the index tree without having to do an additional seek to read the actual row. This strategy can be used when the query uses only columns that are part of a single index.*
- For the other case, **Null** value according the [index type docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-output.html#jointype_index) a full scan table will be performed using reads from this index to look up data rows in the corresponding index order.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the reason for the downvote

Comment: thanks,  you type the error explain reslut about the first sql.